How can I make a translator which convert my dynamic website language English to French
I need to convert my dynamic website's pages from English to French. For this I was using Google's Translation API, but Google translate API is not returning the correct translation of the pages.
What should I to use to get 100% accurate results when translating pages from English to French?
Also give me suggestion if you have better options for this task instead of Google's Translation API.

If it's a dynamic site: you should do it where you change the content.
So let's assume you have a CMS or a database where you store and manage the EN content. When you change this content you could send it to an online translation service, like deepl.com : and store the translation in your DB.
This will "cache" the translation in your own CMS, instead or relying on an ad hoc service like google translate.
If people want to use Google translate for that: the can do it themselves via: https://translate.google.com/?hl=nl&sl=auto&tl=en&op=websites
Till 2019, you could use a widget for that: https://www.weglot.com/blog/google-translate-widget

Use react-i18next with JSON files for static content and a CMS for dynamic content.

How can I start CMS for dynamic content in React App.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
